# Package pdftex.def Error: File `LastFig2a-tif-converted-to.png' not found. ...ludegraphics[width=7.5cm]{LastFig2a.tif}}

Tags: floats, eps, tiff

I have a latex file that includes figures in `PDF` and `PNG` format and compiles well. The journal asked me to convert all the figures to `EPS` or `TIF`. I converted all my figures to `TIF`.
When compiling I got the following error:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `LastFig2a-tif-converted-to.png' not found. ...ludegraphics[width=7.5cm]{LastFig2a.tif}}
```

I use the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

This is the way I use the figures for instance:

```
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[J48 - KDD]{\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{LastFig2a.tif}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[CART - KDD ]{\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{LastFig2b.tif}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[J48 - RLCP]{\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{LastFig2c.tif}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[CART -  RLCP]{\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{LastFig2d.tif}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Accuracy Results for KDDCUP and RLCP dataset}
    \label{fig:DS3}
\end{figure}
```

What do I have to do that I'll be able to compile with `TIF` format as well as with `eps`?

Comment: Erh, latex does not support tif, what exactly are you submitting to?

Comment: I would like to submit a paper to journal (big data journal) and we produced pdf from latex. However, while submitting we got an error and they told us that the figures should be in tif format or eps....

Comment: you need the _original_ images for latex, presumably the journal want the figures _in  addition_ in tiff or eps for their in-house processes.

Comment: So the only thing I have to do is to convert my figures to tiff format?

Answer (score 2):

To make the command

```latex
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
```

work, you need to have the convert tool installed. It comes with imagemagick. So make sure you have imagemagick installed.

Using this kind of command also requires the usage of `--shell-escape` option in the command line. Otherwise your .tif file won't get converted to .png.

Other option is to write a script to convert the image files to png separately and then run pdflatex.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/205592)

Comment: I expanded my answer based on my own findings just yesterday. I managed to get my document working this way. I had the same problem.